# error with content of remote image error swift

Tags: swift

I am getting the following error

> Argument labels '(contentsOf:)' do not match any available overloads

```
extension UIImageView {
    func load(url: URL) {
        DispatchQueue.global().async { [weak self] in
            if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
                if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self?.image = image
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I’m surprised that `DispatchQueue.global()` compiles.

Answer (score 0):

Install kingfisher so much simpler.